Porch ceiling load
How do I know if my front porch is load bearing or not. I am wanting to install a swing. We also having trouble finding the ceiling joists. We tried astud finder and that didn't work. Before rippig dowwn the ceiling figured I should find out if my porch will be able to handle load of swing.

Load bearing walls/beams are at the house and at the end away from the house for porches/similar.  Will need to know how the porch was made.  It probably will hold dead weight(person/s sitting down) straight down, but it when you add swinging to the dead weight, that life can get interesting.  The ceiling looks easy to take a bit down to see what is above, but it seems thin enough a swing would be on the interesting/difficult side.  Depends what those posts are holding up.

House was built in 1991. Single story home @1350 sq ft. Crawl space, asphalt roof, frame construction. Not sure if this helps.

You, no doubt have 2x6 rafters holding the porch roof up.  The ceiling is probably attached to sleepers running 90 deg. to the rafters. Finding the rafters will mean you need to remove some of the ceiling panels.  Attaching a swing will require some additional bracing and brackets .  Exactly what is unknown until the construction is revealed.

Yes, pry off a soffit panel or two (might have to do it on both legs of the roof) and see how it's framed.
